# RecursionError: maxium recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python

I'm new to stack overflow this is my second question so please bear with me. I'm creating a simple calculator program. Here's the code:

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def subtract(x, y):
    return x - y

def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y

def divide(x, y):
    return x / y

print("what do you want to do?")
print("1.Add:")
print("2.Subtract:")
print("3.Multiply:")
print("4.Divide:")

choice = input("Enter a number 1-4 for your operation: ")

def operation():
    if choice == '1':
        print(num1,"+",num2,"=", add(num1, num2))

    elif choice == '2':
        print(num1,"-",num2,"=", subtract(num1, num2))

    elif choice == '3':
        print(num1,"*",num2,"=", multiply(num1, num2))

    elif choice == '4':
        print(num1,"/",num2,"=", divide(num1, num2))
    else:
        print("I SAID A NUMBER 1-4 YOU DUMBASS!")
        return(operation(), input())

operation()
num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter another one: "))
```

whenever I put a number greater than 5 it uses the else statement and loops the print statement over and over for a couple of seconds then print "recursion error: maximum recursion depth exceeded. I know that by putting the return statement inside the function, the function then loops itself over and over. I then tried to add the input to prompt the user for another input but I guess this isn't the right syntax. Can someone post the right syntax for this code or is there a more concise way of doing this? Thank you any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your `else` clause:

```
else:
    print("I SAID A NUMBER 1-4 YOU DUMBASS!")
    return(operation(), input())
```

Notice that you call `operation` again, but you haven't changed the `choice` at all, so `operation` will run again with the same choice you had before (over and over until you hit the recursion limit).

At this point, you're probably tempted to do:

```
choice = input(...)
return operation()
```

However, that won't work either as `choice` is a global variable and if you try to modify it in the function, you'll get an `UnboundLocalError`.

You could declare `global choice` within `operation`, but that's suboptimal.  A better design would be to pass the choice as an argument to `operation`:

```
choice = int(input("Enter a number 1-4 for your operation: "))

def operation(choice):
    if choice == 1:
        print(num1,"+",num2,"=", add(num1, num2))

    elif choice == 2:
        print(num1,"-",num2,"=", subtract(num1, num2))

    elif choice == 3:
        print(num1,"*",num2,"=", multiply(num1, num2))

    elif choice == 4:
        print(num1,"/",num2,"=", divide(num1, num2))
    else:
        print("I SAID A NUMBER 1-4 YOU DUMBASS!")
        choice = int(input())
        return operation(choice)

operation(choice)
```

---

Finally, even once you get this part working, you'll have additional problems depending on python2.x or 3.x.  On python2.x, `input` will be returning numbers, not strings, so your equality tests (`choice == '1'`) will never pass.  On python3.x, the equality tests will work out just fine (because your choice will be a string), but the math equations will break (you can't multiply 2 strings together).

I've fixed that in the example above -- But remember not to use `input` in production code for python2.x as it's a huge security risk.

Comment: else:
      print("I SAID A NUMBER 1-4 YOU DUMBASS!")
      input("enter your choice again: ")
      return operation()

Comment: a better solution is a loop rather than recursion.

Comment: @Copperfield -- You're right about the int-vs.-str thing.  I was clearly not thinking when I made that adjustment.  As far as `while` loops vs. recursion -- I'm not certain that I think there's a huge benefit here.  Certainly the user is expected to not put the wrong input in 1000 times in a row -- And python doesn't have an `until` type statement which would be more appropriate here for looping...  Also, who knows, maybe OP needs to use recursion as part of the assignment?  Mostly I was trying to address the question (Why am I getting a recursion error?)...

Comment: as for the `until` go, you can use `break` or a for-loop with range(n) according to the case. Maybe in this instance is irrelevant what to use either loop or recursion because we don't expect that is used 1000 times in a row, but is good to point it out that a loop is the best choice, after all you don't want your calculator or game or whatever that was working perfectly suddenly crash because you chose recursion

Answer (score 0):

That call is before input so it is calling and calling and calling again. This menu with choices is usually placed inside a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code, one is you are comparing a string with integer and the next one with out changing the value of option you are calling the same function, so it keeps on calling itself never ending, so the compiler giving you recursion error.

Comment: Oops forgot to mark question as solved @mgilson addressed the first issue and I more or less knew of the second but thank you for your help